# Ordering third party Aspect in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hystrix

I have a new Aspect that I would like to apply `@Around` a service method annotated with `@HystrixCommand`. Because of the annotation, the `HystrixCommandAspect` is automatically applied.

However, `HystrixCommandAspect` doesn't define an `@Order`, which I suspect means that it defaults to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (i.e. it should be executed last). I need my aspect to run last because the `HystrixCommandAspect` executes the service method on a different thread and my aspect needs to run on that thread (the reason is probably not important here, but it involves thread local storage).

It seems that when there is a tie in `@Order`, the order is somehow determined by Spring's component scan. Is there a way to manually specify the order that Spring should apply these aspects (given that I can't change the `@Order` of `HystrixCommandAspect`)?

Comment: I've done some more digging and I'm suspecting this is related to spring boot's auto-configuration. Hystrix defines it's own spring.factories, which references HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration, exposing a hystrixCommandAspect bean. I am able to override that bean with my own configuration class (the override only seems to work if I also use auto configuration for my config), which is a copy-and-paste of Hystrix's aspect with an @Order annotation. However, my second aspect class never seems to be added, regardless of whether I'm using auto configuration to add it or not.

Comment: It turns out that the `HystrixCommandAspect` just invokes the method directly rather than proceeding the `JoinPoint`. This is why the aspect that follows is never invoked.  I've raised a [Hystrix bug](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1684).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the `@DeclarePrecedence`, for example:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;

@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("*, com.example.HystrixCommandAspect, com.example.YourCustomAspect")
public class AspectOrder {
}
```

Probably it would require you to switch to AspectJ.

Comment: Hystrix seems to be using spring boot auto configuration, so I'm not certain how that will play with AspectJ.  The auto configuration seems to do its thing, regardless of what I specify in `aop.xml`.

Comment: There is no possibility to explain here all the theory of working with aspectj and spring. You'd better read the corresponding chapter in the official spring core reference manual and spend some time reading their code. 
In short, it doesn't metter for AspectJ who define aspects. You just need to define their locations.
From spring perspective, you don't have to do anything at all (AspectJ takes all the responsibility). But if there is a need for some aspects to become beans (e.g. for DI), then you'll have to instantiate them via special method "aspectOf".